# Which should be used: python-<module> or <module>-python?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, python-module

When creating a Python module/library, which naming convention should be used? I've seen projects like `python-requests` and then ones like `mysql-python`. Should `python` be a prefix or a suffix to the module name? Which is the more adopted/recommended way?

Comment: Are you referring to the name of the project or the name of the package when it's released? Distribution packages usually follow their own naming convention (e.g. [Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:NamingGuidelines#Addon_Packages_.28python_modules.29)).

Answer (score 0):

The [official Python style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) discourages long names in general, and you should use underscores rather than hyphens if punctuation is necessary.  In terms of suffix or prefix, neither are necessary, but either are acceptable.  Of the two, **using "Py" as a prefix is probably the most common.**  For example, [PyQuery](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/), [py2app](https://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/py2app), and [PyX](http://pyx.sourceforge.net/).

Here's some data, drawn from the list of 43,000+ packages available on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/):

```
+-----------------------------------------------+-------+--------+
| Neither starts nor ends with 'Py' or 'Python' | 37943 | 87.40% |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------+--------+
| Starts with 'Py'                              |  3639 | 8.38%  |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------+--------+
| Starts with 'Python'                          |   814 | 1.88%  |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------+--------+
| Ends with 'Py'                                |   796 | 1.83%  |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------+--------+
| Ends with 'Python'                            |   219 | 0.50%  |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Only 10% of Python packages start with "Py", so it's definitely not the most common.

Comment: "Py" is often used as a suffix too - NumPy, SciPy, etc.

Comment: I meant it was more common as a prefix than a suffix.